# Capture output of tabadmin status command in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tableau-api

I want to capture output of tabadmin status command in a Batch Script and print different messages with respect to the services that are down. 
Eg: output of tabadmin status --verbose:

```
'Tableau Server Data Engine' (5980) is running.
'Tableau Server Coordination Service 0' (7528) is running.
'Tableau Server Search and Browse 0' (10172) is running.
'Tableau Server Tabadmin Service 0' (4788) is running.
'Tableau Server Application Server 0' (9876) is running.
```

I want to know all the services that are not running and print them.

Comment: Have you tried `tabadmin status --verbose >log.txt 2>&1`? If so, what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

What about this batch code?

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,3* delims='()" %%A in ('tabadmin.exe status --verbose') do (
    if "%%C" == " is running." (
        echo "%%A" is running with identifier %%B.
    ) else (
        echo "%%A" is not running.
    )
)
```

The command **FOR** executes the command line `tabadmin.exe status --verbose` in a separate command process in background started with `cmd /C` and captures all output written to handle **STDOUT**.

Then **FOR** processes the captured output line by line with ignoring empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon which don't exist in captured output.

The line is split up into substrings (tokens) using the specified delimiters `'()`.

The first substring between `'` is of interest and therefore referenced with `tokens=1`. It is assigned to specified loop variable `A`.

The second substring is just a space character between `'` an `(`. This space character is not needed and is ignored for that reason.

The third substring is the identifier number between the round brackets. This string is of interest and so referenced with `3` in `tokens=` option. It is assigned to next loop variable after specified loop variable `A` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is the loop variable `B`.

And the last substring is everything after `)` up to end of line because of `*` after `3` at end of `tokens=1,3*` which is assigned to loop variable `C`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`